# mediant and weighted mean, fraction

Tags: inequality, means, farey-sequences

Suppose there are several fractions ${\dfrac{a_1}{b_1}}$,…,${\dfrac{a_n}{b_n}}$ and $a_i$ < $b_i$ for 1≤i≤n
all a > 0 and b>0

Mediant of the above fractions

M=(a1+...an)/(b1+⋯+bn)

and the weighted mean of the fractions wrt numerator value

A=${w{\scriptscriptstyle 1}\dfrac{a{\scriptscriptstyle 1}}{b{\scriptscriptstyle 1}}}$ + ${w{\scriptscriptstyle 2}\dfrac{a{\scriptscriptstyle 2}}{b{\scriptscriptstyle 2}}}$ + ... n times

$w_i$ = $\dfrac{a_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}}$

Is it always true that A≥M?
Probably yes, whats the proof. please help

Comment: @GReyes I agree that it's a question OP needs to address, but his formulation is definitely a weighted mean, just with different set of weights (which also add up to one, so it is a convex combination)

Comment: I got it. It makes sense, just had never seen that before.

Comment: Just checked with two fractions, and it is true. If you call the fractions $a_1/b_1$ and $a_2/b_2$, the inequality $A\ge M$ is equivalent to $(a_1b_2)^2+(a_2b_1)^2\ge 2(a_1b_2)(a_2b_1)$ which is obviously true. I guess you can use induction to prove it in general.

Comment: Just checked the general case by induction. It works in general.

Comment: mediant was addressing this but weighted mediant went towards adding weights to M rather than A (as per the question). can you think of something around that? if you can upload induction proof it will be great as well

Comment: Just posted my proof by induction. When you say weighted mediant, what weights are you assuming?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the inequality is true for $n$ fractions. Then we need to prove that
$$
\sum_1^{n+1}w_i\frac{a_i}{b_i}\ge\frac{\sum_1^{n+1}a_i}{\sum_1^{n+1}b_i}
$$
This is equivalent to
$$
(\sum_1^{n}w_j)\sum_1^{n}\frac{w_i}{\sum_1^{n}w_j}\frac{a_i}{b_i}+w_{n+1}\frac{a_{n+1}}{b_{n+1}}\ge\frac{\sum_1^{n}a_i+a_{n+1}}{\sum_1^{n}b_i+b_{n+1}}.
$$
Using the inductive hypothesis,
$$
(\sum_1^{n}w_j)\sum_1^{n}\frac{w_i}{\sum_1^{n}w_j}\frac{a_i}{b_i}+w_{n+1}\frac{a_{n+1}}{b_{n+1}}\ge (\sum_1^{n}w_j)\frac{\sum_1^n a_i}{\sum_1^n b_i}+w_{n+1}\frac{a_{n+1}}{b_{n+1}}
$$
(observe that the weights are the right ones, corresponding to the first $n$ fractions). Using the fact that we know the inequality is true for two fractions, 
$$
(\sum_1^{n}w_j)\frac{\sum_1^n a_i}{\sum_1^n b_i}+w_{n+1}\frac{a_{n+1}}{b_{n+1}}\ge \frac{\sum_1^{n}a_i+a_{n+1}}{\sum_1^{n}b_i+b_{n+1}}=\frac{\sum_1^{n+1}a_i}{\sum_1^{n+1}b_i},
$$
as desired (in the last formula, the weights are again the right ones).

Comment: After Using the inductive hypothesis, the expression on RHS is substituted on induction n=2 where first number is (a1 to an) and second is $a_{n+1}$ and you are substituting by higher value but preserving <= sign

Comment: I am using the inductive hypothesis to say that the first term in the left hand side is $\ge$ than the first term in the right hand side. I can do that because there are only $n$ fractions there, with the right weights on the left hand side.

Comment: I only have two fractions after I use my hypothesis with $n$ fractions: one is $\sum_1^na_i/\sum_1^nb_i$ and the other one is $a_{n+1}/b_{n+1}$ and I know the inequality works for two fractions because I checked that before (some simple algebra)

Comment: agree that it works for n=2. my point is : –
$\frac{\sum_1^{n}a_i+a_{n+1}}{\sum_1^{n}b_i+b_{n+1}}$ <= $(\sum_1^{n}w_j)\frac{\sum_1^n a_i}{\sum_1^n b_i}+w_{n+1}\frac{a_{n+1}}{b_{n+1}}$
you are substituting RHS here with something that is bigger, you can only have something smaller. if you think you are right, i will think again.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I wrote. I do not see any problem. I replace the LHS by smaller things until I get the desired RHS.

Comment: LHS $\ge\frac{\sum_1^{n}a_i+a_{n+1}}{\sum_1^{n}b_i+b_{n+1}}$

another one :
$(\sum_1^{n}w_j)\frac{\sum_1^n a_i}{\sum_1^n b_i}+w_{n+1}\frac{a_{n+1}} {b_{n+1}} >= \frac{\sum_1^{n}a_i+a_{n+1}}{\sum_1^{n}b_i+b_{n+1}}$

won't mean LHS >= $(\sum_1^{n}w_j)\frac{\sum_1^n a_i}{\sum_1^n b_i}+w_{n+1}\frac{a_{n+1}} {b_{n+1}}$

Comment: Honestly,  I do not see your point. I want to prove $A\ge B$. I use the inductive hypothesis to prove $A\ge C$ and then the fact that it holds for $n=2$ to prove that $C\ge B$. I conclude by transitivity that $A\ge B$.

Comment: right, got it. you wrote "using inductive hypothesis" there. thanks!
i got stuck at RHS got translated to something bigger using induction and inequality was held. like A >= C, ,B>=C and we did A>=B. my bad